# Angular Directive that uses same model, but different data

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am trying to create a custom directive for pagination that exists in 2 places on my page.  I have 2 tables of data that I want to use the same pagination directive.  Here is my directive

```
app.directive('pagination', function () {
        return {

            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div ng-if="!isLoading" class="backup-pagination">\
                        <input type="button" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage = currentPage - 1" value="Prev" />\
                        <span>{{ currentPage+1 }} / {{ numberOfPages(backupList) }}</span>\
                        <input type="button" ng-disabled="currentPage >= backupList.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage = currentPage + 1" value="Next" />\
                    </div>',
            scope : {
                currentPage: '=',
                backupList: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

            }
        }
    });
```

And here is the DOM

**This is one pagination directive for a table**

```
<div ng-if="!isLoading" pagination backup-type="active" current-page="ActiveCurrentPage" backup-list="data.ActiveBackups"></div>
```

**And here is another one for a another table**

```
<div ng-if="!isLoading" pagination backup-type="inactive" current-page="InactiveCurrentPage" backup-list="data.InactiveBackups"></div>
```

The problem is that my pagination directive does not seem to have access to the parent scope of the controller. It seems like `numberOfPages()`, which exists on the controller `$scope` is not getting called. Same thing with `pageSize`. What do I have to do so that this 1 directive can be used all of my application using different data sets?

**HTML**

```
<div id="active-backups" class="backup-table-wrap">
            <h3>Active Backups</h3>
            <table id="active-backups-table" class="backup-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Last Archived</th>
                        <th>Archive Size (GB)</th>
                        <th>Mailboxes</th>
                        <th>Items</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-if="isLoading">
                    <tr load-spinner></tr>
                </tbody>

                <tbody  ng-if="!isLoading">
                    <tr ng-repeat="active in data.ActiveBackups | paginate:ActiveCurrentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
                        <td><a ui-sref="order.overview({ orderId: active.ServiceId })" ng-click="select(active)">{{ active.Customer }}</a></td>
                        <td>{{ active.LastArchived }}</td>
                        <td>{{ active.ArchiveSizeGB | number:2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ active.NumMailboxes }}</td>
                        <td>{{ active.ArchivedItems }}</td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="backup-restore-btn" value="Restore" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div ng-if="!isLoading" pagination backup-type="active" current-page="ActiveCurrentPage" backup-list="data.ActiveBackups"></div>

        </div>


        <div id="inactive-backups" class="backup-table-wrap">
            <h3>Inactive Backups</h3>
            <table id="inactive-backups-table" class="backup-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Last Archived</th>
                        <th>Archive Size (GB)</th>
                        <th>Mailboxes</th>
                        <th>Items</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                 <tbody ng-if="isLoading">
                    <tr load-spinner></tr>
                </tbody>

                <tbody  ng-if="!isLoading">
                    <tr ng-repeat="active in data.InactiveBackups | paginate:InactiveCurrentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
                        <td><a href="#">{{ active.Customer }}</a></td>
                        <td>{{ active.LastArchived }}</td>
                        <td>{{ active.ArchiveSizeGB | number:2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ active.NumMailboxes }}</td>
                        <td>{{ active.ArchivedItems }}</td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="backup-restore-btn" value="Restore" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                <div ng-if="!isLoading" pagination backup-type="inactive" current-page="InactiveCurrentPage" backup-list="data.InactiveBackups"></div>


        </div>
```

Comment: You've created a new scope with your directive. If you want to use the parent scope you have to either pass in the function or use $parent.numberOfPages(backupList)

Answer (score 5):

That's because you declared an isolate scope on your directive, meaning it doesn't inherit the parent `$scope` of the controller and creates a new one every time its created. You could keep your isolate scope and pass in other requirements of the directive along in that scope as well, rather than relying on getting it from the parent controller via inheritance, IMO this approach is much more cleaner and explicit.

```
 scope : {
           currentPage: '=',
           backupList: '=',
           numberOfPages: '&'
         },
```

and pass in the function like this:

```
<div ng-if="!isLoading" pagination backup-type="inactive" current-page="InactiveCurrentPage" backup-list="data.InactiveBackups" number-of-pages="numberOfPages()"></div>
```

Comment: This makes sense, however, if every single one of my pagination directives uses the same "numberOfPages", shouldn't there be a better way to call that function that reduces code redundancy

Comment: For example, instead of having to put number-of-pages="numberOfPages()" on every pagination directive, I can just do `scope.$parent.numberofPages()` within the link function

Comment: That's a good point, to which I have no good answer. It may seem like code redundancy but when you think about it a bit, it's not really causing a maintenance issue by supplying that function in each directive deceleration. You're probably going to have what one or two of these on a page, if more you would put the directive declaration code in an ng-repeat which makes the repetition a lot less apparent. Edit: you could do that, but I'm more of a fan of passing that function in again rather than doing scope.$parent. I mean if you use that directive in another page you need to make sure that

Comment: `numberOfPages` exists on that page's controller `$scope`, but when you explicitly define a need for `mumber-of-pages` in the view template, you make it a lot more cleaner and explicit that the directive needs `numberOfPages`. I tend to favour a bit more code duplication than having this implicit dependency.

Comment: Ok that makes sense for numberOfPages, but what about using the current page attribute. Because the current page is relative to what data set we are talking about. Meaning there are actually 2 currentPage values on my page.  When we hit Next and Prev, I need the parent scope's `ActiveCurrentpage` and `InactiveCurrentpage` to update accordingly.  Should I attempt to reference those values directly from the directive? Or should I use $scope.$apply() to change the values within the directive?

Comment: IMO it would be better to have that inside the directive itself, i mean you're making a directive to make life simpler and things cleaner so your controller shouldn't have to keep a copy a reference to the current page, that should be the responsibility of the directive.

Comment: If I do that though, then how will my `ng-repeat` know what page we are on for each set of data? My pagination has to actually work, meaning my `ng-repeat` uses filters to use ActiveCurrentPage and InactiveCurrentPage to determine the "page" of each table

Comment: Ok so after looking at the `scope` values within the directive after a "next page" change, I notice that the value of `scope.$parent.ActiveCurrentPage` changes accordingly, except the DOM is not aware of the change. I think I need to $apply() it at some point

Comment: From my pov you have two options: pass in each piece of data you want to use into your directive (explicit::good), or don't create a new scope and piggyback on your parents (implicit::ugly).

Comment: It's not a matter of getting the values into the directive...its changing the parent scope values once we change it in the directive

Comment: if I explicityly send my directive the current page of that data set (ie. current-page="ActiveCurrentPage" or current-page="InactiveCurrentPage") then when I modify currentPage inside my directive, the values of ActiveCurrentPage and InactiveCurrentPage do not change and my pagination just doesn't work

Comment: It is hard for angular to watch primitive variables, try creating an object in your controller with the data you want {activePage:1...}, then the two-way binding should hold.

Comment: Oh I think I realized why it isn't changing the correct value in my controller... when I inspect the `scope` variable within my directive, it appears that the values I need to change are actually at `scope.$parent.$parent.ActiveCurrentPage` instead of just `scope.$parent.ActiveCurrentPage`. Not sure why there is an extra `$parent`

Comment: @MattHintzke if your directive is in an ng-repeat it would create another scope too.

Comment: @ZackArgyle It is not. It lives inside a view that my Controller is controlling, therefore it should not have another `$parent`, unless creating a view using ui-router creates another scope as well.. Hmmmm im confused

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for now, but I would really like to figure out how to do this the proper way. What I did was send in a callback function to the directive like this:

```
<div ng-if="!isLoading" pagination backup-type="active" on-change="onPageChange" backup-list="data.ActiveBackups"></div>
```

where `onPageChange` is the call back function that lives on my controller's `$scope`.  Next I wired up my page changes to call that callback function every time the page is changed

```
scope.nextPage = function () {

     scope.currentPage++;
     scope.onChange(scope.currentPage, attrs.backupType);

}
```

Then I set up my callback on `$scope` like this

```
$scope.onPageChange = function (newPage, type) {
            console.log(newPage);
            if (type == 'active') {
                $scope.ActiveCurrentPage = newPage;
            } else {
                $scope.InactiveCurrentPage = newPage;
            }
        }
```

This solved my problem, but it does not feel like the "correct" way.